# Post request to WebAPI2

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I writing REST service using WebAPI2

I need to add book to db.

I have this code Model:

```
 public class Book
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public string Author { get; set; }
 public int Year { get; set; }

}
```

And Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void CreateBook([FromBody]Book book)
    {
        db.Books.Add(book);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

I try to send POST request from postman

[image]

But I have this error

> "Message": "The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.",
>       "ExceptionMessage": "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Book' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'."

How I can hadle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add a formatter to the HttpConfiguration object, if this is an ASP.NET MVC project, you will find it in the WebApiConfig.cs class under the Register method

```
 public class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            //Routes
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(/// your routes);

            //Formatters
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank's.
It helps

Comment: Web API supports `application/json` by default.  You should not need to add it manually to the supported media types.

Answer (score 5):

You are getting this error because the `Content-Type` header being sent with the request is `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`.  This is happening because you have selected the "form-data" radio button in Postman, which automatically sets the `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data` regardless of whether you have entered a header manually.  (This is covered [in the documentation](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests)-- see "Note about headers" in the "Request Body" section about 2/3 of the way down the page.)  Try selecting "raw" instead, and ensure you have added a `Content-Type` header with a value of `application/json`.  Then, add your JSON in the Body section.

```
{
    "Id": 1234,
    "Name": "A Book About Nothing",
    "Author": "Joe Schmoe",
    "Year": 1993
}
```

Comment: This should be the answer.